# Magento 2 Setting custom customer attributes

Tags: magento2, php, customer, custom-attributes, checkbox

I have some custom attributes set in the customer information in the admin.

I have a page setup with checkboxes which if checked should set these attributes to yes or no.

I'm struggling with setting the values after the checkbox has been clicked.

Here's my code:

```
var_dump($customer->getCustomAttribute('new_products_attr'));
?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('form_before') ?>
<form class="form form-newsletter-manage" action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getAction()) ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <div class="customCheckbox">
            <label for="subscription" class="control control--checkbox">
                Newsletter subscription
                <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" id="subscription" value="1" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('General Subscription')) ?>"<?php if ($block->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox">
                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
            diam nonummy nibh euismod
            tincidunt ut laoreet dolore</p>
        </div>
        <div class="newProducts customCheckbox">
            <label class="control control--checkbox">
                New products
                <input type="checkbox" name="newProducts" id="new_products" <?php if($customer->getCustomAttribute('new_products_attr') == true):?> checked="checked" <?php endif; ?>/>
                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
            diam nonummy nibh euismod
            tincidunt ut laoreet dolore</p>
        </div>
        <div class="exclusiveOffers customCheckbox">
            <label class="control control--checkbox">
                Exclusive offers
                <input type="checkbox" name="exclusiveOffers" />
                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
            diam nonummy nibh euismod
            tincidunt ut laoreet dolore</p>
        </div>
        <div class="discountsAndSales customCheckbox">
            <label class="control control--checkbox">
                Discounts and sales
                <input type="checkbox" name="discountsAndSales" />
                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
            diam nonummy nibh euismod
            tincidunt ut laoreet dolore</p>
        </div>
        <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.newsletter.extra') ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary"><button type="submit" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Save')) ?>" class="action save primary"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Save')) ?></span></button></div>
        <div class="secondary"><a class="action back btn" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Back')) ?></span></a></div>
    </div>
</form>
<?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.newsletter.extra2') ?>
<script>
require(["jquery"], function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var ckbox = $('#new_products');
        <?php $data = true; ?>
        $('input[name="newProducts"]').on('click',function () {
            if (ckbox.is(':checked')) {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: please accept and upvote answer. So, It's useful for other also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code :

```
protected $customerRepositoryInterface;
public function __construct(
    ............................
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ............................
) {
    ............................
    $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    parent::__construct($context);
    ............................
}
public function execute()
{
    $customer =$this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerID);
    print_r($customer->getCustomAttribute('new_products_attr')->getValue());
}
```

It maybe helpful for you.